# What does require('../') mean?

Tags: node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Node.js - require empty path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359582/node-js-require-empty-path)

What does `require('../')` mean in the context of node.js? Example code [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/e61305299c9e6d233656a878278922cb04c99aa6/examples/logger.fast.js).

Comment: I guess all modules from parent folder?

Comment: My guess also. Is there documentation out there?

Comment: I've never used it, but I think it is this project: http://requirejs.org/, the implementation (../) should load all modules from parent folder.


  [1]: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Example code link is not valid.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A folder can be used as a module if the folder contains any of the following files (in lookup order): `package.json`, `index.js`, or `index.node`.

In this case, the folder has a `package.json` file that, among some other things, states that the main file of the module is the `index.js` file in the same directory. So the `require('../')` call you asked about could be changed to `require('../index.js')`.

See [Node.js Documentation - Folders as Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It requires the file `index.js` of the parent folder, which is this one: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/index.js