# what is use of require('.') in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I was reading a node.js cli module documentation and it has one line like this. I know that we can include external modules like this but dont know what is the use of '.' while requiring a module;

`const foo = require('.');`

Can anyone tell me what is use of it or why its used that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - require empty path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359582/node-js-require-empty-path)

Comment: Node JS Assumes the existence of an `index.js` file when no file name is provided. So `require('.')` to node is `require('./index.js')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will import index file in the folder where you are running your file will empty require statement. Javascript require module will try to find `index.js` file if you do not specify any file name(only provide folder reference) in the require() argument.

Basically it's an alias for `const foo = require('./index.js');`

**index.js**

```
module.exports = 1;
```

**foo.js**

```
const foo = require('.');
console.log({ foo });
```

If both files are in the same folder then it will print

```
{ foo: 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In require('.'), '.' represent the current directory, and ".." means parent directory.

```
-- parent 
  -- child1
    -- grandchild1
    -- grandchild2
  -- child2
```

Now, suppose you are at child1 and want to import files from grandchild1 or inside the subfolder, Then you have to start from the current location (".") to the grandchild location.

```
require('./grandchild1/filename')
```

and, if need to import from the parent or outside your current directory, then you have to start backward that is from parent location (".."):

```
require('../parent/filename') 
// here '..' take you one folder back (parent folder) and if you want to go one more folder back (parent of parent folder) then add one more pair of dots : '../../some_folder'
```