# What does require('..'); in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I found this in [here](https://github.com/mongodb-js/kerberos/blob/master/test/kerberos_tests.js) what is the explanation of this line?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359582/node-js-require-empty-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file that's in is in the `kerberos/test` directory. `..` from there is the `kerberos` directory, so it's basically equivalent to `require('kerberos')`, except using the one that it's inside instead of searching for one by that name.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph, Seems to be It also similar to `require('../')`